# Error: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

Good day ! 
I'm creating a program for the end of school year. But the famous problem of " 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable" is come. I don't now where is the mistake. 
The program :

```
def Setfenetre():

    #New window
    fenetre= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 464), FULLSCREEN)
    background=pygame.image.load("Ressources/Images/Set_window4.jpg").convert()
    fenetre.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    #BoutonSOUND(ON/OFF)
    SOUND_area = pygame.Rect((280,55), (250,50))
    rect_surf = pygame.Surface(SOUND_area.size)
    rect_surf.set_alpha(0)

    #BoutonRETURN
    RETURN_area = pygame.Rect((315,165), (171,45))
    rect_surf = pygame.Surface(RETURN_area.size)
    rect_surf.set_alpha(0)

    #Son clic:
    soundClic= pygame.mixer.Sound("Ressources/Sons/Clic.wav")

    #SonON/OFF / Sorti de Setfenetre
    jeu=1
    while jeu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if  SOUND_area.collidepoint(event.pos) or RETURN_area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if event.button== 1:
                        soundClic.play()
                if SOUND_area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if event.button== 1:
                        soundMainMenu.stop()
                if RETURN_area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if event.button== 1:
                        jeu=0
                        fenetre("MainMenu")
        fenetre.blit(rect_surf, RETURN_area)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
```

Python tells me this error : (TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable)
PS :
My pygame window is not init. because it is does in an other fonction named "fenetre()".

Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: What is `fenetre("MainMenu")` supposed to do? `fenetre` is an instance of pygame.Surface – Is the name `fenetre` used twice?

Comment: Basically when this error is raised, it means that you tried to use `()` on an object which, like said, is not callable i.e. it does not have the `__call__` method implemented.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the function fenetre("MainMenu") is a Menu, and with a button on the window, the function Setfenetre() is starting. And same thing for this window : a button "return" can starting the function fenetre("MainMenu"). So, when I play the program, I do the command "fenetre("MainMenu")" to display the menu. The name "fenetre" is used twice for call this function

Comment: @kaktus_car yeah it's why I don't understand the mistake :-|

Comment: @GuiLLaume You have to use a different name, either for the function or for the local instance of the Surface. The Surface (`fenetre= pygame.display.set_mode(...)`) covers the function, because they have the same name

Comment: @Rabbid76 but how can i do change the name ? This function will not be recognized ?

Comment: @GuiLLaume Then rename the surface.

Comment: @Rabbid76 ooh ok it's work !!! Thanks you very much for your rapidity and your help !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different name, either for the `fenetre` function or for the local instance of the `fenetre` *Surface*. The Surface (fenetre= pygame.display.set_mode(...)) "shadows" the function, because they have the same name.
Change the name of the display *Surface* variabel and each use of it:

<s>`fenetre= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 464), FULLSCREEN)`</s>

```py
fenetre_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 464), FULLSCREEN)
```